# Prove if $\{x^iy^jz^k \mid i \le2j\text{ or }j \le 3k\}$ is regular or not

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

$$L = \{x^iy^jz^k \mid i \le2j\text{ or }j \le 3k\}$$

To Prove: If given language is regular or not.

I know that it is not a regular language but I am not able to come up with the string which I can use in the pumping lemma to prove that it is not regular.

We can also divide $L$ into two parts:
$$\begin{align*}
L_1 &= \{x^iy^jz^k \mid i \le 2j\}\\
L_2 &= \{x^iy^jz^k \mid j \le 3k\}\,,
\end{align*}$$

so I just need the strings to be used in the pumping lemma for $L_1$ and $L_2$.

Comment: Decomposing the language $L$ into union or intersection of two simpler languages is useful to prove that $L$ is regular, but it will not help you (in general) to prove that $L$ is not regular. The union  or intersection of two non regular languages can be regular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not regular. **Hint**: Let $p$ be the integer of the pumping lemma and pump the string $x^{6p}y^{3p}z^{2p}$.

Answer (score 2):

Decomposing the language $L$ into union or intersection of two simpler
languages is useful to prove that L is regular, but it will not help
you (in general) to prove that $L$ is not regular. The union or
intersection of two non regular languages can be regular.

However, you can use these closure properties differently, to
eliminate $x$. Consider the language $R=x^*y^*$. This language is
regular. Its intersection with $L$ is $L'=L\cap R=\{x^iy^j \mid i \le
2j\}$  keeping only the words were $z$ has exponent $0$.
This is because $L_2\cap R=\{\epsilon\}$. So $L'=L\cap R=(L_1\cup L_2)\cap R=(L_1\cap R)\cup(L_2\cap R)=(L_1\cap R)\cup\{\epsilon\}=L_1\cap R$ because $\epsilon\in L_1\cap R$.

If $L$ were regular, then $L'$ would also be regular because $R$ is
regular, and the intersection of regular languages is regular.

Thus if you can prove that $L'=\{x^iy^j \mid i\le 2j\}$ is not
regular, you can infer that $L$ is not regular.

And you should be able to prove it for $L'$.

There are other ways of using closure properties to simplify the
language. For example you could use an erasing homomorphisn to replace
all $z$ by the empty word, which would lead you to the same language
$L'$, And regular languages are closed under arbitrary homomorphism.

Closure properties can be very friendly, if you learn to use them. Then can considerably simplify some problems. See [How to prove that a language is not regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular)

With thanks to [**Hendrik Jan**](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/4287/hendrik-jan) for catching a shameful bug.

Comment: @HendrikJan You are right... I wanted to show how to use closure. Actually I first did it with $k$ using an erasing homomorphism. Then I thought a student might not know that, and I looked for intersection with a regular set, but the *or* had become an *and* in my mind ... hence the mistake. I am correcting.